# Class Sequence in C++?

Tags: c++, class, sequence

I have following code but it cannot find classes below the parent class:

```
class Child
{
public :
    static void Exe()
    {
        Program::COUT();
    }
};


class Program
{
public :
    static void Run()
    {
        Child::Exe();
    }

    static void COUT()
    {
        cout << "Child Executed!";
    }
};
```

The error is:

> Cant find Program Class!!!

Comment: You need a forward declartion for `class Program` before `Child` and move the implementation of `Child::Exe()` to a separate compilaton unit.

Comment: OMG!!! ONOZ!!! But seriously... you can't call a function that wasn't declared before it's used. Also, this use of static functions is silly. If you want to organize your functions into logical groups, use namespaces.

Comment: `static class` won't compile.

Comment: If the only purpose of the class is to keep related functions together then using a namespace with functions is preferable. Also I'm fairly sure `static class` doesn't actually mean anything in c++ and is invalid syntax.

Comment: Coming from Java, are we?

Comment: Ok Ok , dont do that, im new to c++ and StackOverflow! Please Help me...

Comment: You need to start from the basics, forget Java, and learn C++. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you StoryTeller ;-), i used C#.NET before, android and asp...but new in c++ , thanks anyways.

Comment: Thanks Rabbiya Shahid ;-)

Comment: Here's another thing worth remembering. Use the @ character to tag someone in a comment (like so @StoryTeller) . Otherwise people won't know you are addressing them. I only noticed because I came back for a peek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to take your presumably java code and put that in c++ syntax You could do this:

```
class Child
{
public :
    static void Exe(); //forward declaration
};


class Program
{
public :
    static void Run()
    {
        Child::Exe();
    }

    static void output()
    {
        std::cout << "Child Executed!";
    }
};

void Child::Exe(){
    Program::output();
}
```

But really this I think is poor design. If you want to write more idiomatic C++ then you don't just want to be in the habit of creating classes without needing the other functionality of classes. Specifically if the classes are only being used to keep functionality grouped by name then using a `namespace` is much cleaner:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace Program{//forward decleration
    void output();
}
namespace Child{
    void Exe(){
        Program::output();
    }
}

namespace Program{
    void Run(){
        Child::Exe();
    }

    void output(){
        std::cout << "Child Executed!";
    }
}
int main(){
    Program::Run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very Very nice and clear!, thanks bro! ;-)